# What website is appropriate for asking questions related to legitimacy, details of online websites?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I wanted to buy a few parts so after searching I came upon this website. I want to know if this website is fake so which website is appropriate for asking this question?

Comment: "this website" is ambiguous. I suppose you don't mean Meta Stack Exchange. Can you make it more clear?

Comment: By *"which website"*, do you mean *"which Stack Exchange site"*?

Comment: The [equivalent of rating bureaus exists for web sites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trustpilot). Some amount of sodium chloride may be needed in any case.

Answer (score 6):

None of the sites within the SE network will take that question.

Answers will be highly opinion based, hear say or wild guesses. No future visitors will value those answers, no experts will risk their reputation on that. It is unlikely a knowledge base with high quality, long lasting content will emerge.

Try a traditional forum, Reddit, Quora, Facebook or Twitter. I hear those are good for getting opinions.

Comment: No help on Quora :(